# Integrate nonparametric curve in R

Tags: r

Just a warning, I started using R a day ago...my apologies if anything seems idiotically simple.

Right now im trying to have R take in a .txt file with acelerometer data of an impact and calculate a Head injury criterion test for it. The HIC test requires that curve from the data be integrated on a certain interval.

The equation is at the link below...i tried to insert it here as an image but it would not let me. Apparently i need some reputation points before it'll let me do that.

[image: equation]

a(t) is the aceleration curve.

So far i have not had an issue generating a suitable curve in R to match the data. The loess function worked quite well, and is exactly the kind of thing i was looking for...i just have no idea how to integrate it. As far as i can tell, loess is a non-parametric regression so there is no way to determine the equation of the curve iteslf. Is there a way to integrate it though?

If not, is there another way to acomplish this task using a different function?

Any help or insighful comments would be very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Wes

One more question though James, how can i just get the number without the text and error when using the integrate() function?

Comment: Can't you 'integrate' by linear interpolation between subsequent datapoints and calculating the area under the lines each time (trapezium)? It looks like you won't need the accuracy anyway (since you are willing to accept a loess as the function approximation)?

Comment: Well the issue with using the points themselves rather then a fitted line is that sensors tend to give quite a bit of noise...the goal is to smooth this out. I actually think using a line like a loess as an approximation will in reality be closer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `predict` function on your `loess` model to create a function to use with `integrate`.

```
# using the inbuilt dataset "pressure"
plot(pressure,type="l")

# create loess object and prediction function
l <- loess(pressure~temperature,pressure)
f <- function(x) predict(l,newdata=x)

# perform integration
integrate(f,0,360)
40176.5 with absolute error < 4.6
```

And to extract the value alone:

```
integrate(f,0,360)$value
[1] 40176.5
```

Comment: One more question though James, how can i just get the number without the text and error?

Comment: @user1003131 Ben's comment is correct, I'll add it to the answer

Comment: @user1003131 Feel free to accept this answer as correct, as a thank you to who helped you out.

Comment: @Nick Sabbe- Thank you for pointing that out, I am new to this forum and was not aware of it.